# Exiting a running script with any button

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script in which I'm trying to add the functionality of exiting upon keypress. Thus far, my code looks like what you see below:

```
keyinput=''
if [ -t 0 ]; then stty -echo -icanon -icrnl time 0 min 0; fi
  while [ "x$keyinput" = "x" ]; do
   echo "Press Any Key to Exit."
   echo "Users currently logged on:"
   w #Display who is currently logged on
   echo "Disk space utilization:"
   df -h #Display disk space utilization in human readable form
   echo "Memory and CPU Utilization:"
   ps axo user,pmem,pcpu #Display Username, % of Memory Used, CPU Usage %
  keyinput="`cat -v`"
  done
if [ -t 0 ]; then stty sane; fi
echo "Thanks for using the Live Monitor, you pressed '$keyinput' to exit."
```

For some odd reason, I can not get the exit on any key input to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
keyinput="`cat -v`"
```

For

```
read -r -n 1 keyinput
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. One other question, let's assume I call that script that from another script with a line like wait -n 5 ./thisscript.sh. When I try to quit with the keypress, it doesn't work. However, when the 'thisscript.sh' is run by itself, the key press on exit works just fine

Comment: Please open a new question, that is a very different issue. It is the usual action to accept an answer when it solves the question. Will you accept this answer, Please?.